# Analytical Continuation of Integral Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to better understand analytical continuation and got myself the following problem, to analytically extend the function $F(z)$ of the complex variable $z$, where $\alpha$ is a parameter
$$F(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha}{z + \alpha^2}$$.

I went down the following road, taking $z$ positive the integral converges and is actually easy to compute, yielding
$$F(z) = \frac {\pi} {\sqrt{z}} \qquad z>0$$

Now I thought it is all a matter of assigning a proper meaning to the square root by choosing a branch cut, as I myself known the square root function has a branch point at zero. I can then start from the value taken by $F$ for $z$ positive, and then move to complex values.

But here lies my problem: if I take the branch cut as going from the branch point to negative infinity the function $F$ is discontinuous in passing from, say, $z + is$ to $z - is$. This seems OK, but if I understand properly, the choice of branch cut should be pure arbitrary convention. In this case the latter choice seems "privileged" choice, as the integral diverges for $z$ real and negative). Indeed, if I place the branch cut along the positive imaginary axis, will the divergence of the integral result in a pole of $F$? This is qualitatively different from the function obtained by the previous choice of branch cuts.

Thanks so much for helping me.